# Anyway to hint compiler to optimize out scope_failure's destructor when there is no exception?

Tags: c++, exception, optimization, c++17, uncaught-exception

Consider the following code:

```
# include <exception>
# include <cassert>

# define INLINE [[gnu::always_inline]]

template <class F>
class scope_failure
{
    F f;

public:
    constexpr INLINE scope_failure(F &&func) noexcept: 
        f{std::move(func)}
    {}

    INLINE ~scope_failure() noexcept
    {
        if (std::uncaught_exceptions())
            f();
    }
};

void F1() {
    scope_failure s{[]() noexcept { assert(false); }};
}

int main() {
    F1();
}
```

As you can see, in `void F1()` there is no exception being thrown, thus the `~scope_failure` should do nothing and it can be even being optimized out because only in the context of which an exception is thrown will it matters.

I compiled the code using `clang++-6.0 -std=c++17 -S` and it turns out that this optimization does not happen. What I want to ask is, is there any way to do this?

Edit, an explanation of motivation for this optimization:

IMHO, this is a very important optimization. It enables `zero-cost abstraction` for code that use either `scope_success` or `scope_failure` to do `cleanup` or to make `assertion` in 
 it, that is, part of the `contract programming`.

Further more, if compilers can optimize this code, they might also be able to **optimize** the code of the registered `destructor` for `exception-handling` code to callback, Ex. remove the `if` in `scope_failure` and execute the registered callback function directly, or remove the registration of `scope_success` for `exception-handling` code for they will do nothing when an exception is being thrown.

Comment: A destructor should not ever throw, and should hence not tagged `noexcept` as that's what it is by default.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - Wut? A destructor certainly may throw. It's just *usually* a bad idea, so the default exception specification is `noexcept(true)` anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller When is throwing in a destructor ever a good idea?

Comment: My phrasing was wrong. Someone could throw in a destructor, but that should make any code reviewer throw up as well :p

Comment: Not sure [[gnu::always_inline]] works with clang? godbolt seems to say no?

Comment: @PasserBy - `scope_success([]{ throw Up{}; })` - The destructor of the scope success object has to be able to deal with throwing correctly correctly, that's one. By its very nature as a general purpose utility.

Comment: @StoryTeller Isn't that the exact opposite? As in, the only destructor `noexcept(~scope_success()) == true` because it discarded all exceptions?

Comment: @PasserBy - Huh? The scope success object calls the functor when the scope is exited normally, not via exception. So if the scope is exited normally, why can't a user decide to provide a throwing functor? The scope_success object may certainly not discard exceptions.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher ```clang++-6.0``` seems to work well with ```[[gnu::always_inline]]```.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am just used to the default ```noexcept(false)``` for non-destructor so I marked it as ```noexcept``` explicitly. However, I will argue that it is not a programming mistake and there is no need to pay so much attention to it.

Comment: @PasserBy Throwing is a good idea in the dtor when it's a good idea elsewhere.

Comment: You have to store the value of `std::uncaught_exceptions` in the constructor and compare it in the destructor; there’s a reason it’s not a `bool` (anymore).

Comment: @Davis Herring Well, this is something I didn't consider... I thought whatever called in ```scope_failure``` should not throw, since it is the cleanup code. If anything goes wrong, maybe it should just call  ```std::terminate``` instead of throwing anything.

Comment: Throwing an exception during cleanup is terrible and hard to cope with, IMHO the cleanup code should be designed to be ```noexcept``` or just terminate.

Comment: Which means the cleanup code shouldn't use ```scope_failure``` anyway.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: It’s not about what `scope_failure` might call; it’s about using `scope_failure` *in* a (subroutine of a) destructor invoked while an exception is *already* propagating.

Comment: @DavisHerring I know, that is why I said the cleanup code shouldn't use ```scope_failure```. This is a simplified version for normal code that won't be called during cleanup on exception failure.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: Sorry for misunderstanding.  You can certainly provide a simplified version—but why shouldn’t “cleanup code” do something that might throw, so long as it catches the exceptions?

Comment: @Davis Herring In that case, all exception is explicitly catched, there is no need for ```scope_failure```. Either the ```catch``` block calls ```std::terminate``` directly, or it can do the cleanup code or assertion itself, no need for using ```scope_failure```. Besides, when such thing happen, there's barely anything you can do with it -- even your cleanup code is failed.

Comment: @Davis Herring The reasons that ```scope_failure``` is preferred over ```catch``` is that its syntax is more readable and it doesn't require to pay for the (potentially high) price of ```catch``` block. Having a ```catch``` inside the function will defeat the purpose of ```scope_failure```.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: There indeed must be a `catch`, but it need not be in the same function as the use of `scope_failure`.

Comment: @David Herring True, that is where my version of ```scope_failure``` fails to work correctly...But since cleanup functions are special, I think it will probably be implemented separately using raw ```C``` function call, so I didn't think of that... But, you are right. It fails under that circumstance.

Comment: I will close this question because what I want is actually an ```API``` that can indicate whether the destructor is called by the ```exception handling``` code or not.